# Bootstrap' pull right or pull left class with !important?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been coding in regular CSS and one thing to avoid is not to use `!important`  unless it is necessary. I am now trying to use bootstrap but it doesn't give a regular helper float class, instead it gives `.pull-right` and `.pull-left` with `!important`.

Should I consistently use them across project or should I avoid to use it when not necessary?

Comment: I must tell you that you question is not suitable for this site, as It will lead into opinion base answers. you should post problems which are more object oriented and not subjective

Comment: @Nilesh Mahajan I cant' agree with you.  Its same like saying OOJS is opinioned. "!important" greatly affect structure of css's order and may cause bugs when using javascript to change css properties.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a simple CSS class that bootstrap brings with it and in the reference is now further warning, it's fine in my opinion to use `pull-right` and `pull-left`. I use it too, and I never accounted any problems. I think, both are the regular helper float classes in bootstrap.

Usually, you have a really good reason to use pull-right and pull-left, if you want to float your containers in the given way. So maybe some other classes, which may combined with the pull-* classes, use float, too. But it's important, that your hand choosen pull-class wins and that's the reasons for `!important`.

Conclusion: it's fine to use the `pull-*`-classes.